# Unknown chars when reading a txt created in windows

Tags: windows, text, string-formatting

When reading this with `std::cout`

```
1   31.13   31.38   31.16   31.53   29.81   28.59   28.53   29.50   30.63   31.88   33.25   33.38   32.41   32.56   31.75   30.91   31.25   31.50   30.44   29.91   30.22
```

In between every character I have a reversed `?`.
Does anyone know how I can reformat this text so I don't get unexpected hidden characters?

This is a very basic txt files with a row of numbers that probably needs convertion from Windows

Comment: Maybe the text is saved in a 16-bit character set, and read as 8-bit? What exactly do you mean by "reading this"? Which language? On the console in in a GUI?

Comment: `cout` is output, not input. Any reasonable text editor should show the encoding used. For example Notepad++ shows it in the status bar and you can use the "Encoding" Menu to change it.

Comment: is there a way to change it through code?

Comment: Sure. But encodings are a complex field. I suggest you search for "C++ and unicode" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Before fixing the problem with code, first you need to find out what is the encoding of the text.
The content is most likely in `UTF-16` and you're reading it as `ANSI`.

To find out what encoding it is, open the file using a binary editor such as 010 Editor, Hex Workshop, or even simply read the content as a byte array.

You can also open the file with an editor such as Notepad++ or SublimeText to see what encoding it is and change the encoding from the menu.